# Checkbox input using MaterializeCSS and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, datatables, thymeleaf, materialize

Hey there so I am using Spring Boot and Spring Web with Thymeleaf. For the frontend I use MaterializeCSS and datatables with [this](https://codepen.io/azamatms/pen/ZGwOMM/) styling CSS/JS.

I want to display a table where the user can select datasets that are parsed in there with Thymeleaf iteration. I tried doing it with a form of a CheckBoxWrapper that contains a list of CheckBox elements. The CheckBox Elements themselves contain a single boolean value.
You can find my full code at the end of this question.

But if I try to do it like this (I think?) Thymeleaf generates another hidden input field directly after the checkbox. The HTML in the browser then looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS0ER.png)
which results in the checkbox not being displayed by the browser. If I (re-)move the generated hidden input outside the label the checkbox gets displayed correctly.
[See the difference on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTY7r.png)

Is there a way to get the checkbox displayed correctly while still being able to get the checkbox input to the server? (with Thymeleaf)

If you need some additional information regarding anything problem related please let me know.

Code - HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>This is some really important detail</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/materialize.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/datatables.css}" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="admin" class="col s10 offset-s1">
        <div class="card material-table">
            <div class="table-header">
                <span class="table-title">Table Headline</span>
                <div class="actions">
                    <a href="#" class="search-toggle waves-effect btn-flat nopadding"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form action="/submit" th:object="${checkBoxWrapper}">
                <table id="datatable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Check</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <th:block th:each="element,status : ${persons}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" th:id="'checkbox'+${status.index}"
                                               th:field="*{list[__${status.index}__].val}"/>
                                        <span>Desc</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <th:block th:text="${element.name}"> -</th:block>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </th:block>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/datatables/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/script/datatables.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/script/materialize.js}"></script>
</html>
```

Code - Controller

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model){

        List<Person> pList = new ArrayList<>();
        pList.add(new Person("Mick"));
        pList.add(new Person("Kevin"));
        pList.add(new Person("Joe"));
        model.addAttribute("persons", pList);

        List<CheckBox> cList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++) {
            cList.add(new CheckBox(false));
        }
        CheckBoxWrapper checkBoxWrapper = new CheckBoxWrapper(cList);
        model.addAttribute("checkBoxWrapper", checkBoxWrapper);

        return "/home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/submit")
    @ResponseBody
    public String submit(@ModelAttribute CheckBoxWrapper checkBoxWrapper){

        return "success";
    }
}
```

Code - CheckBox

```
public class CheckBox {

    private boolean val;

    //Getter, Setter, Constructor

}
```

Code - CheckBoxWrapper

```
public class CheckBoxWrapper {

    List<CheckBox> list = new ArrayList<>();

    //Getter, Setter, Constructor

}
```

Code - Person

```
public class Person{

    String name;

    //Getter, Setter, Constructor

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can move the hidden input ABOVE the checkbox, you're good:

```
<label>
   <input type="hidden" name="_list[0].val" value="on"><!-- First is ok! -->
   <input type="checkbox" /><!-- I still display -->
   <span>Red</span>
</label>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/MWwjxaP)

Just to note, the markup is very strict here - as in each unique checkbox and span pairing must be wrapped in their own label. Any variation from this will break the component.

https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
So what would you recommend to change the order? Just using JS?

Comment: JS could work, it's pretty hacky but may be your only option. The preferable way would be to control how/when/where Thymeleaf is outputting the hidden input. Do you have any option to manipulate this?

Comment: I don't have a clue where I could tell thymeleaf to put this hidden input above the checkbox. 
I got it working with JS. If I find a better solution I will share it :)

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, the problem is the order in which the input elements are rendered. As of *thymeleaf-spring 3.0.10* you can just set the very self-explanatory property `spring.thymeleaf.render-hidden-markers-before-checkboxes=true` either in the *application.properties* file or, at runtime, in the *SpringTemplateEngine* configuration avoiding any client-side hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the accepted answer as a starting point (the key being that the order of the inputs matters), I managed to come up with a workaround that requires minimal js. Just needed to manually create the hidden field and checkbox and name them appropriately so Spring could find their respective values upon submit. The hidden field must be prefixed with "_" and the checkbox must have a numeric index at the end of the id. The values for each can be derived from the backing field using Thymeleaf expressions.
For example, if the backing object named "myForm" has a field named "mySwitch", you can do the following:

```
<label>
   <input type="hidden" name="_mySwitch" th:value="${myForm.mySwitch} ? 'on'">
   <input type="checkbox" id="mySwitch1" name="mySwitch" th:value="${myForm.mySwitch} ? 'true'" th:checked="${myForm.mySwitch} ? 'checked'">
   Off
   <span class="lever"></span>
   On
</label>
```

Unfortunately this still requires some js to set the values appropriately for submit. Using jQuery:

```
$('#mySwitch1').click(function(){
   if ($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this).val('true');
      $('#_mySwitch').val('on');
   }else{
      $('#_mySwitch').val('');
   }
});
```

This will correctly read the current value from the Spring @ModelAttribute and set the appropriate state for the switch upon page load, as well as provide the correct value upon submit. Hope this helps someone.